# access denied you need (at least one of) the super privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: cpanel

DELIMITER $$ -- -- Procedures -- CREATE DEFINER=`vipmarke_user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getcat` (IN `cid` INT)  SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id=cid$$  DELIMITER ;

Comment: Hi, your question isn't very specific. Can you add more details so that someone understands what you're after.

Comment: when we import in cpanel, we face this problem. store procedure don't support cpanel.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER=`vipmarke_user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getcat` (IN `cid` INT)  SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id=cid$$

DELIMITER ;